# Vim jump to next match without affecting search pattern

Tags: vim

Is there a way to jump to a fixed string in VIM without affecting the search history?

Say I want to use the key `;f` to jump to the next `function`, and `;s` to the next `section`.

I can do this:

```
nmap ;f /function<CR>
nmap ;s /section<CR>
```

These work fine, but they overwrite the last search pattern.  I want to jump nut keep the old search string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call vim function `search()`

```
nmap ;f :call search('function')<CR>
nmap ;s :call search('section')<CR>
```

Comment: Also depending on your language you might want to look at `]]`. See `:h ]]` for more information.

Answer (score 3):

kev's answer is simple and fine; for a more advanced approach, you can use my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130). With it, you can define mappings that jump backward / forward to the [count]'th occurrence of `function`, beep when there are no more matches, etc.